# Permission granted mysql user cannot access the particular database Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql-cluster, mysql

I used

```
grant all on mydb.* TO user1@"localhost" identified by "user1"
```

And getting following error when access the mysql from a separate physical box.

This is a mysql cluster(Mysql server version 5.1.56). And connector jar is mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar.

Any ideas?

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user1'@'166.31.44.23' (using password: YES)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
>           ...

Comment: Did you tell the server to reload the grant tables, i.e. with "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"? See [When Privilege Changes Take Effect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privilege-changes.html)

Comment: Change your connection string to point to localhost, not to 166.31.44.23

Comment: ... or grant the rights to 'user1' or 'user1'@'166.31.44.23' ... and use the right password too (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the password is also "user1", you are using the [grant syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) incorrectly: The `identified by` parameter is for the *password* (not the username).

Try this:

```
grant all on mydb.* TO 'user1'@'localhost' identified by 'mypassword'
```

Comment: @VMai fair enough (remark removed). I wasn't sure only because I have never seen it coded with double quotes

Comment: I would consider the use of single quotes as good practice myself. The use of the username as password not ... And then there's the problem Alberto mentioned too. I didn't saw it before your edit of the question.